# Prolog - Format the output of a grid table

Tags: printing, grid, prolog

I want to print a 9x9 grid with indications for the number of the line and column, I want the elements to be left-aligned.
Like so:

```
> L\C | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 9 |
> --------------------------- 
> 1   | a | b | a | ... | b |
> --------------------------- 
> 2   | a | b | a | ... | b | 
> ... 
> 9   | a | b | a | ... | b |
```

The content of the table has variable size (the max size of an element is 9 char's), so the table might not be aligned if there is no use of *tabs* *\t* like so:

```
> L\C | 1 | 2 | 3 | ... | 9 |
> --------------------------- 
> 1   | aaaaa | bb | aa | ... | bbbbb |
> --------------------------- 
> 2   | a | bbbbb | aaa | ... | bb | 
> ... 
> 9   | aaaaaaa | bbbb | a | ... | bb |
```

I have the content of the table saved in a list of lists.Like this:

```
initialBoard([[sunTile, free, free, free, sunTile, free, free, free, sunTile],
                [free, sunTile, free, free, free, free, free, sunTile, free],
                [free, free, sunTile, free, free, free, sunTile, free, free],
                [free, free, free, free, free, free, free, free, free],
                [sunTile, free, free, free, free, free, free, free, sunTile],
                [free, free, free, free, free, free, free, free, free],
                [free, free, sunTile, free, free, free, sunTile, free, free],
                [free, sunTile, free, free, free, free, free, sunTile, free],
                [sunTile, free, free, free, sunTile, free, free, free, sunTile]]).
```

For what I researched in the prolog documentation, I have to use *format/2*.

Any idea how can I do this, simple and fast?

Comment: Have you read the documentation in detail on `format/2`, particularly the format arguments? I took a quick look at the SCISTUS documentation and they have a lot of examples for each of the format string options. Look especially at `~N|`, `~N+`, and `~Nt`, and there are several examples given for column alignment. I think it's spelled out pretty clearly. Have you experimented with `format/2` in the Prolog command interface to see how it behaves?

Comment: @lurker Yes, I did try! But I can not figure out how to do it correctly.
I tried to print a line of elements with tabs:
`format('|~s~t-5||~s~t~5|', [free, free]).`

It was an error, I just can not understand this predicate

Comment: You're going to need to make your columns wide enough to hold the widest value you want. Also, the `format` you show (`format('|~s~t-5||~s~t~5|', [free, free]).`) has a syntax error: `-5` should be `~5`. You need to show exactly what you tried in your question (edit your question to add information), and show exactly what error you saw. You also need to show exactly how you want your second example to look when it's done correctly (*e.g.*, are the columns supposed to be centered or left justified or...?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just taking the example from the SICSTUS Prolog manual and modifying it for your data, this will give you centered columns:

```
?- format("|~a~t~5||~t~a~t~8+|~t~a~t~8+|~t~a~t~8+|~n", [1,foo,bar,bah]).
|1   |  foo  |  bar  |  bah  |
true.
```

And this will give left justified columns:

```
?- format("|~a~t~5||~a~t~8+|~a~t~8+|~a~t~8+|~n", [1, foo,bar,bah]).
|1   |foo    |bar    |bah    |
true.
```

The `~5|` fixes the column position at column 5. Then, think of the `~t` as a sort of springy filler. So the `~t~a~t` centers, between the previous and next column settings, the argument that `~a` corresponds to, `~t~a` would right-justify it, and `~a~t` would left-justify. The `~8+` says to go to the column 8 positions after the last set position and establishes the next "boundary" relative to which the filler operates.

To get a row separator:

```
?- format("|~`-t~29||~n").
|----------------------------|
true.
```

In other words, `~t` would be your springy space, but, as described in the documentation,

```
~`ct
```

will use the character `c` as filler.